# CSS + Align Text by ':'

Tags: html, css

I have the following text:

[image]

I want to align the ':' so they are in a straight line - just easier to read.

eg:

topic:
  domain:
  origin:
    date:

[image]

Is there an easy way to get the ':' to lineup? thx

Comment: I see you're already using a table. You can take it a step further, I guess, by breaking the labels and values into their own cells and aligning them accordingly.

Comment: @Boltclock He's not using a table for _layout_... he's using it to display this data, which is OK. I'm not charmed about the use of `<b>` though

Comment: @Mr Lister: Oops. I guess I was thinking of the alignment... never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the labels and values in separate elements, then align the label to the right and the value to the left.

For table cells:

```
<td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">Topic:</td>
<td>Creating an account (Joining)</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of using table it's better to move headings into their own column:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: right">Topic:</th>
    <td>Creating an account (joining)</td>
  </tr>
  …
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `<th>`. You might want to suggest not putting the styles inline though; that would improve readability and save space.

Comment: Yes, if you have external stylesheet it's better to style `th` with something like `table th { text-align: right }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a definition list: [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2216403)

CSS:

```
dt { display:block; float:left; width:100px; text-align: right;}
dt:after{content:':';}
dd { display:block;}
```

HTML:

```
<dl>
   <dt>aaa</dt><dd>111</dd>
   <dt>bbbbbbb</dt><dd>22222</dd>
<dt>cccccccccc</dt><dd>33333333</dd>
<dt>dd</dt><dd>44</dd>
<dt>eeee</dt><dd>5555555</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

use tables

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>name </td><td>: Bob</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>age </td><td>: 20</td>
</tr>
</table>
```